# Why is my Web Deployment failing with a time out exception

Tags: build-automation, webdeploy

I am trying to set up auto deployment of a website in the build process. I can publish via Visual Studio 2012, but when I try to have TFS build auto deploy I get a timeout error.

Here is my command to the TFS build process:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MSDeployServiceUrl=http://<MyServer> 
/p:DeployIisAppPath="InitiationTool" /p:UserName=BGRSDEV\admin /p:Password=<mypassword>
```

Here is the error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (4193): Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=InitiationTool'.)

Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=InitiationTool'. The operation has timed out
```

I have tried running the msdeploy.exe dump command and get the same behavior.

This works:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:dump -source:iisapp="InitiationTool",computername=http://<MyServer>/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE,username=BGRSDEV\admin,password=<mypassword>
```

This times out:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:dump -source:iisapp="InitiationTool",computername="http://<MyServer>:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=InitiationTool",username=BGRSDEV\admin,password=<mypassword>,authType=basic -allowUntrusted
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the answer elsewhere but in case anyone comes here, I needed to use https, not http. And I needed to add the flag for the untrusted certificate.  /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True

Comment: in my case is was just a matter of using https instead of http.
thanks for the tip!

Comment: Using HTTPS and the /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True and still seeing occasional timeouts.

Comment: Damn! Saved me a day! Replacing http with https worked for me!
Thanks a million @Noel